# Compact + chain-connected metric space => connected

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, connectedness

How to show that if $M$ (a metric space) is compact and chain-connected then it is connected ?

Definition of $\varepsilon$-chainable :

$(X,d)$ is $\varepsilon$-chainable if given any two points $a,b\in X$, there exists a finite set $\{x_0,x_1,...,x_n\}$ of points in $X$ with $x_0=a$, $x_n=b$ and $d(x_{k−1},x_k)<\varepsilon$, for all $0<k\leq n$.

A metric space is chain-connected if it is $\varepsilon$-chainable for all $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Hint: A disconnected compact metric space can be partitioned into two non-empty compact subsets $A$ and $B$. What do you know about the distance between $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @LukasGeyer probably I understand it!because A and B are compact,there exist positive r that distance between every two points of A and B are greater than r.if we choose epsilon smaller than r there is no chain-chainable between two points of A and B and this is contradiction.

Comment: @m.a You should write an answer to your own question. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer.